# Why is $\frac{1}{2}\frac{b^{2}-a^{2}}{b-a} = \frac{a+b}{2}$?

Tags: fractions

Why is $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{b^{2}-a^{2}}{b-a} = \frac{a+b}{2}$$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider that $b^2-a^2 = (b+a)(b-a)$

Comment: Ah now i see, i thought $b^2-a^2 = (b-a)^{2} = (b-a)(b-a)$ which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{b^{2}-a^{2}}{b-a}$$
=$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{(b+a)(b-a)}{b-a} =\frac{a+b}{2}$$